# Масштабирование в ImageView

Tags: android, изображения

В `ImageView` загрузил картинку

```
img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tank);
```

Хочу изменять размер, перемещать пальцами по экрану.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делать!

Answer (score 3):

Я использовал [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom). Вроде бы неплохо, есть альтернативы.

> Android ImageView widget with zoom and pan capabilities

Comment: Еще есть отличная реализация https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/

Comment: это внешняя библиотека!!!!!!!
как ее подключить

Comment: @tankevich2007, это очевидно, что это внешняя библиотека, зачем столько знаков восклицания?    
Подключать ее как и любую другую внешнюю библиотеку.

Answer (score 2):

Скачай эту полезную программу: [Libraries for developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=ru). Там есть то, что ты ищешь, и еще много чего классного для разработчика.

Answer (score 0):

Масштабирование в ImageView осуществляется изменением свойства

```
scaleType
```

у экземляра этого визуального компонента.